# PHP: avoid displaying the same product twice?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm using the following code to create a search function for my site using PHP/MYSQL.

This code will search for sizes and colors if the checkboxes are selected and will display them in on my page.

example:

```
checkbox 1 = small
checkbox 2 = large
checkbox 3 = xxlarge
checkbox 4 = red
checkbox 5 = black
etc etc ......
```

if the users select `small and large as the size and red as the color`, my PHP will return the products that have those *credentials*.

This is the PHP code:

```
<?php
error_reporting(-1);
ini_set('display_errors', 'On'); 
include "config/connect.php";
$searchList = "";
$clause = " WHERE ";//Initial clause
$sql="SELECT *
FROM `yt`
INNER JOIN `ATTRIBUTES` ON yt.id=ATTRIBUTES.id";//Query stub
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    if(isset($_POST['keyword'])){
        foreach($_POST['keyword'] as $c){
            if(!empty($c)){
                ##NOPE##$sql .= $clause."`".$c."` LIKE '%{$c}%'";
                $sql .= $clause . " (ATTRIBUTES.sizes LIKE BINARY '$c' OR ATTRIBUTES.colors LIKE BINARY '$c')";
                $clause = " OR ";//Change  to OR after 1st WHERE
            }
        }
        //print "SQL Query: $sql<br />"; //<-- Debug SQl syntax.
        // Run query outside of foreach loop so it only runs one time.
        $query = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql);
        //var_dump($query); //<-- Debug query results.
        // Check that the query ran fine.
        if (!$query) {
            print "ERROR: " . mysqli_error($db_conx);
        } else {
            // Use $query inside this section to make sure $query exists.
            $productCount = mysqli_num_rows($query);
            $i=0; // count the output amount
            if ($productCount > 0) {
                while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
                   $id = $row["id"];
                   $product_name = $row["product_name"];
                   $searchList .= ''.$product_name.'';
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
?>
```

**THE ISSUE THAT I HAVE:**

if A product has *small and large* (both)  as the credentials, and the users search for small and large, my PHP will return the same item **twice**.

how can I stop the php returning the same product twice in cases like above?

any advise would be appreciated.

I have used GROUP BY as suggested like so:

```
$sql="SELECT *
FROM `yt` GROUP BY yt.id
INNER JOIN `ATTRIBUTES` ON yt.id=ATTRIBUTES.id"
```

but that throws the following error:

```
ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'INNER JOIN `ATTRIBUTES` ON yt.id=ATTRIBUTES.id WHERE (ATTRIBUTES.sizes LIKE BIN' at line 3
```

Comment: Try `SELECT DISTINCT * ....` http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-distinct.aspx

Comment: @ʰᵈˑ,  no, that doesn't work. it still returns the duplicated items. because the items table is separated from the colors and size table. sorry, I should have mentioned that in my question.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use SQL "GROUP BY" function. If yt.id is your product id,that'd be "GROUP BY yt.id" appended to your query.

Try:

```
<?php

error_reporting(-1);
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
include "config/connect.php";
$searchList = "";
$clause = " WHERE ";//Initial clause
$sql="SELECT *
FROM `yt`
INNER JOIN `ATTRIBUTES` ON yt.id=ATTRIBUTES.id";//Query stub
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    if(isset($_POST['keyword'])){
        foreach($_POST['keyword'] as $c){
            if(!empty($c)){
                ##NOPE##$sql .= $clause."`".$c."` LIKE '%{$c}%'";
                $sql .= $clause . " (ATTRIBUTES.sizes LIKE BINARY '$c' OR ATTRIBUTES.colors LIKE BINARY '$c')";
                $clause = " OR ";//Change  to OR after 1st WHERE
            }
        }

        //append "GROUP BY"
        $sql .= " GROUP BY yt.id ";

        //print "SQL Query: $sql<br />"; //<-- Debug SQl syntax.
        // Run query outside of foreach loop so it only runs one time.
        $query = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql);
        //var_dump($query); //<-- Debug query results.
        // Check that the query ran fine.
        if (!$query) {
            print "ERROR: " . mysqli_error($db_conx);
        } else {
            // Use $query inside this section to make sure $query exists.
            $productCount = mysqli_num_rows($query);
            $i=0; // count the output amount
            if ($productCount > 0) {
                while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
                    $id = $row["id"];
                    $product_name = $row["product_name"];
                    $searchList .= ''.$product_name.'';
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: same error. in fact I tried it like yours first before I tried it the other way. both throw the same error.